# How does Gazerbeam find out the password to Syndrome's plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-incredibles

In *The Incredibles*, Mr. Incredible finds out what Syndrome's plan is by logging on to his computer with the password "KRONOS" which he discovers with a little post-mortem help by Gazerbeam:

[image: Syndrome's password]

But how did Gazerbeam find the password in the first place? Did *he* do the same thing as Mr. Incredible (getting jobs from Syndrome) only for it to fail and he gets killed in some way? If anyone knows the answer to this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Syndrome was prone to monologuing - that classic villain trait of explaining everything before you kill someone.  Kronos was the name of the 'project' not just a password.

Comment: @iandotkelly if so that means his personal security was a joke! No wonder he was beaten.

Comment: The room with the computer had lots of physical security.  Plus the base is on an otherwise deserted tropical island - and he has a ton of guards.

Comment: @iandotkelly even so. Think about this. Imagine that you were hell-bent on logging out all the other mods so that you were the only one left and you lived on a desert island with Terminators as guards, but your password to your account was "iandotkelly". You're still gonna get hacked and stopped by the all-seeing Shog.

Comment: i assumed that Gazerbeam got the same job as other heroes and later discovered Syndrome's plot but was too late before Syndrome's anti-hero bowling ball was upgraded and set on him so the best he could do was get the password. also it seems Syndrome was infected with the well known disease called Plot Induced Stupidity because one of the basic rules of computer security is that you don't use easily guessable passwords.....like the name of the project the computer has access to. Syndrome is a tech wiz and you're telling me he doesn't know that simple rule?

Comment: You appear to be assuming that Syndrome's computer (and the files therein) were connected to the internet somehow.  Given that this entire project was of his own creation (and top secret, to boot) it's entirely possible - even probable - that he wrote it all himself, locally.  If everything was stored locally and the computer didn't even have internet access (where's he going to find an ISP on that island anyway?), then there would be no way to hack it without first gaining physical access to the machine.  Which would be difficult because guards, remote island, etc.

Comment: I think we're getting off topic...

Answer (score 4):

[Pixar wiki](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Gazerbeam) says

> Gazerbeam was one of several retired supers who were recruited to battle an Omnidroid on Nomanisan Island as part of the droid's battle education. He destroyed the Omnidroid v.X4, then was bested by its successor, the Omnidroid 5. **He was killed by the 5, but not before learning about Operation Kronos. Though the film does not show how, he learned the password for Syndrome's database, "KRONOS," and used his powers to carve it on the wall of a cavern before he lost his life**.

While this was not explicitly shown in the movie, it's not too difficult to deduce how Gazerbeam may have chanced upon the password. You see, Syndrome like the stereotypical villains he once wanted to catch has fallen into a similar pattern. He has started *monologuing* once he believes the superhero is well within his clutch and nowhere to run. Cue scene on Nomanisan Island after Mr. Incredible makes his escape and Syndrome zaps him with the freeze beam. He even acknowledges that Mr. Incredible had him monolouging when Mr. Incredible slyly moves away to chuck a fallen piece of tree trunk or rock at him.

I believe something similar may have happened when he bested Gazerbeam. The megalomaniac that he is, he probably couldn't resist unveiling his grand plan to Gazerbeam in his final moments. On his last breath, Gazerbeam probably jumped into the waterfall that Mr. Incredible jumps into later and reaches the cave where eventually Mr. Incredible finally finds him (or rather his skeleton).

Now, Syndrome may not have gone to the extent of saying, "Hey Gazerbeam! The password to my system is KRONOS". But he almost certainly would have dropped the name Operation **KRONOS** and Gazerbeam in his dying moments etched on the walls of the cave the only piece of valuable intel he had, hoping that someday it might help someone bring down Syndrome.